# Given two DFA's, how can I check that the language generated by the first DFA is included in the one generated by the second one?

Tags: regular-language, dfa, formal-languages, nfa

I have to give an algorithm to check whether given two DFA's, the language generated by the first one is included in the generated by the other one. 
For example, suppose that the first language recognizes the words over {a,b}* that have length 2, while the second one recognizes the words over {a,b}* that have length 3 or less. In this example the first language is included in the second one. 
One of my ideas y to minimize both DFA's and see if the states and transitions in DFA1 are also included in DFA2, but I think it is not a good solution.

Comment: Create a DFA that is the intersection of the two DFAs. If every accepting state in the first DFA is still a reachable accepting state in the intersected DFA, then the first language is a subset of the second. I think.

Comment: I think that your solution is correct. I have thought a similar way using intersection. First you create a DFA3 which is the intersection of DFA1 and the complementary of DFA2. If DFA3 does not have a final state form its initial state, then DFA1 is included in DFA2, otherwise it is not included.

Comment: Welbog suggests intersection, but why not just difference? If L(M2) is a subset of L(M1), then L(M2) \ L(M1) is the empty set. So, construct a machine for the difference and see if it accepts any strings. You could run a DFS from the initial state OR minimize it and see whether you end up with a DFA with one non-accepting state.